# Reading characters from a file and storing as NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to read in a text file and save character arrays as NSStrings.

For example, if the file contains just the word "Hello" I want to have an NSString containing "Hello"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

*filePath* should be a string with the path to file
*encoding* (`NSStringEncoding`) will contain the encoding used
*error* (`NSError *`) will contain an error if one occurs
*string* will contain the contents of the file or will be `nil` if an error occurred

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `NSString` instance method `-initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` or the 'convenience method' `+stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`

In the first instance:

```
NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

In the second:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

where

- `pathToFile` is an `NSString` that is the path to the file you're reading
- `encoding` is one of the `NSStringEncoding` constants (have a look at the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW59))
- `error` is a pointer to an `NSError` object which is populated by the methods if an error occurs.

The choice between the two depends on whether you want an autoreleased string at the end or not.

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like:

`NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file/goes/here.txt"];`
 if you know the exact path of the file.

Comment: You will usually be better using the factory method detailed by Darren Clark below, but remember that it is an autoreleased instance, so you may need to retain it if you want to keep it around.